# How to get underlying stock from ADR

Tags: stocks, banking, international, adr

How can I get the underlying stock from an ADR? What are the fees and general bureaucracy to archive this. Does this depend on the ADR emitting bank, or is a generalized process?

Answer (score 1):

[How do I convert my foreign shares into ADRs and vice versa?](https://www.adr.com/Investors/FAQs)

> To convert your ADRs back into foreign shares, you should instruct your broker to cancel the ADRs, and provide him or her with complete delivery instructions in the issuer's home country.

Comment: it is worth noting that this may not always be possible, as there may be capital controls in the home country, or the company deliberately only trades on a foreign stock exchange for the lower reporting requirements (like non-US companies listing as an ADR...)